# Sub-domain wildcard routing in Laravel 4.2

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

I'm working on a web app and I'm intending on routing usernames as sub-domains and returning their details based on that.

So far I have

```
Route::group('{user}.mysite.dev', function($user) {

    Route::get(('profile', ['uses' => 'UserController@profile']);

});
```

And in nginx I have the following as my server name.

```
server {
    server_name: *.mysite.dev;
}
```

In my hosts locally I have `*.mysite.dev` as a host file entry.

My first major problem is that I get server not found. Second problem, how do I pass $user from the group in Laravel, into the controllers?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: There's actually a matching example in the laravel docs: [http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#sub-domain-routing](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#sub-domain-routing). Have you tried this?

Comment: *My first major problem is that I get server found*. Did you want to mean **server NOT found**.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your server as `mysite.dev`

In your controller, you can get the `$user` parameter as follows:

```
public function profile($user) 
{
    //
}
```

And, your domain route group should be:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{user}.mysite.dev'), function()
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting "This webpage is not available"

Comment: Do you have a way to define an alias for `mysite.dev` so that you can set that as `*.mysite.dev`? In apache one would set it up as follows: `ServerAdmin [email]
        ServerName mysite.dev
        ServerAlias *.mysite.dev
        DocumentRoot [path-to-laravel-install-public-folder]`